# How is this JSON string supposed to be parsed to get the different fields

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have this JSON string that I am recieving after I make a purchase from the playstore and I am apparently missing something in my code when I am trying to parse it.

```
PurchaseInfo:{"orderId":"12999763165555505758.1317333586444405",
    "packageName":"com.mypkgname.myapp",
    "productId":"monthly_purchase_01",
    "purchaseTime":1357456489000,
    "purchaseState":0,
    "purchaseToken":"yrynypfkdncvhlxdbypysvwz.AO-J1OxFkndfqkClAqbbYAOApkMgTG4VX9Ef0uNP0FIs9-xGrXivkbx3FNMA2yNU12K_sbvRGFcknVBTfisI-uZawCXLGlMX4v4Zw8GFOmS0Q6PIbiITTGqn5h1QbEB4Rv84sXdUJHP3B_UQfujZN7ADi9bm_N4_iA"}
```

Here is the snippet of code I am using it to attempt the parsing

```
       try {

            JSONObject j1 = new JSONObject(tester1);             
                JSONArray mPurchInfo = j1.getJSONArray("PurchaseInfo");          

                int count = mPurchInfo.length();

                final String[] purchInfo = new String[count];
            JSONObject q1 = mPurchInfo.getJSONObject(0);

            purchInfo[0] = q1.getString("orderId");
                    purchInfo[1] = q1.getString("packageName");
                purchInfo[2] = q1.getString("productId");
                purchInfo[3] = q1.getString("purchaseTime");
                purchInfo[4] = q1.getString("purchaseState");
            purchInfo[5] = q1.getString("purchaseToken");
                orderID=purchInfo[0];

          } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error","Yes");
          }
```

I am catching the an error as I see this last log statement in my log but I am still trying to learn the parsing JSON Strings

I hope I am at least close
Ideally I would like to have Strings set to all the values in the JSON String

orderID = ??
packageName = ??
etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have this JSON string that I am recieving after I make a purchase from the playstore

If that's *really* what you get back, you need to contact them and tell them to fix their API; that string is not valid JSON. There are two problems with it:

1. A JSON document **must** have an object or array as the top-level item. The string as quoted is missing a `{` at the beginning and a `}` at the end.
2. All keys in JSON **must** be in double quotes. The first one, `PurchaseInfo`, is not.

Also, your code is doing this:

```
JSONArray mPurchInfo = j1.getJSONArray("PurchaseInfo");
```

...but if it *were* valid JSON, `PurchaseInfo` wouldn't be an array, it'd be an object.

Looking at it, if you remove the `PurchaseInfo:` at the beginning, it's valid. Once you've removed that, this line:

```
JSONObject j1 = new JSONObject(tester1);
```

...will give you an object from which you can query information:

```
String orderId = j1.getString("orderId");
```